# How do i get rid of the red error screen that comes up for 2 seconds while using the provider to ftech data?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using StreamProvider to get updates of the current location to then use it on the full_screen_map. everything seems to be working as expected and i am getting locations updates. But when the map is loading, a red error screen with error: `Error: The widget FullScreenMap tried to read Provider<UserLocation> but the matching provider returned null.`

To fix the error, consider changing `Provider<UserLocation>` to `Provider<UserLocation?>`.

I tried to add the `?` to the UserLocation as suggested but the error persist and it only last about 2 seconds while the data is loading, after that everything works as expected. I did tried to have a spinkit or a Circularprogressindicator to try to make it fancy while it waits for the data, THE ERROR PESIST!

I am willing to cosnider a way to just shut up the error in the UI while it could still be shown in the terminal.

this is the main widget build

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<UserLocation?>(
      initialData: null,
      create: (context) => LocationService().locationStream,
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        initialRoute: LoadingScreen.id,
        routes: {
          LoginScreen.id: (context) => const LoginScreen(),
          SignupScreen.id: (context) => const SignupScreen(),
          LoadingScreen.id: (context) => const LoadingScreen(),
          FullScreenMap.id: (context) => FullScreenMap(),
          ForgotPasswordScreen.id: (context) => const ForgotPasswordScreen(),
        },
        theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
          textTheme: const TextTheme(
            bodyText1: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the full_scree_map file where im trying to use the provider

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  UserLocation userLocation = Provider.of<UserLocation>(context);
  Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
  LatLng centerLocation =
      LatLng(userLocation.latitude, userLocation.longitude);

  LatLng trackedLocation =
      LatLng(userLocation.latitude, userLocation.longitude);
```

This is the UserLocation class

```
class UserLocation {
  final double latitude;
  final double longitude;

  UserLocation({required this.latitude, required this.longitude});
}
```

This is the code where the LocationService resides.

```
class LocationService {
  late UserLocation _currentLocation;

  Location location = Location();

  // keeps track of our currefinal nt location

  final StreamController<UserLocation> _locationController =
      StreamController<UserLocation>.broadcast();

  LocationService() {
    location.requestPermission().then((granted) {
      location.onLocationChanged.listen((locationData) {
        if (locationData != null) {
          _locationController.add(UserLocation(
              latitude: locationData.latitude!,
              longitude: locationData.longitude!));
        }
      });
    });
  }

  Stream<UserLocation> get locationStream => _locationController.stream;

  // this function gets the current location
  Future<UserLocation> getLocation() async {
    try {
      var userLocation = await location.getLocation();
      _currentLocation = UserLocation(
          latitude: userLocation.latitude!, longitude: userLocation.longitude!);
    } catch (e) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('could not get the location $e');
      }
    }
    return _currentLocation;
  }
}
```

any help will be appreciated. again, if you know how to just stop the UI from showing that error for those 2 seconds is fine with me. I tried using some codes i found on here like this one `

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
void main() {
    RenderErrorBox.backgroundColor = Colors.transparent;
    RenderErrorBox.textStyle = ui.TextStyle(color: Colors.transparent);
}
```

to stop the red screen error from showing, but no luck.

Comment: First of all check, which exact value cause that red screen issue and handle that particular value in init state.

Comment: I tried to initialized the UserLocation inside the InitState and no luck.

Comment: So maybe that value is not causing this error. It. Will be something else. You can trace exact line of code by using exception breakpoint in VScode